# Adding directory or jar file to environment variables

Tags: java, jar, path, environment-variables, classpath

If class is located in a package, then do we need to add directory or jar file that contains package directories to the **CLASSPATH** or to **PATH** environment variable?

Comment: can you tell us what you want to do? do you want to start an application or use the class in your project?

Comment: @MartinFrank to use the class only.

Comment: you need to add the jar file to the classpath

Answer (score 0):

The PATH environment variable has **nothing** to do with an java classpath.